# What about I published a mislabelled figure in a paper?

Tags: errors-erratum

Recently I discovered that an axis of one the figures from a paper that I published was mislabelled. Unfortunately, the figure also is the graphical abstract. However, the information in the text (paragraphs, conclusions, calculations, tables) is perfectly correct so a careful reader can figure out the right range and undestrand that It was just a label error. Is it necessary a corrigendum?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correcting small errors in text/picture after publication?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/125637/correcting-small-errors-in-text-picture-after-publication)

Answer (score 2):

It is good to inform the editor and offer to provide a corrected version. "Necessary" is a judgement call. If people have been misled or have pointed it out, then more necessary than otherwise. Note that figures can carry a lot of information, so they can, in principle, carry a lot of misinformation.

But offering the correction is the correct action. People make mistakes. It's good that you found it.

Comment: My ex advisor is the correspondent author and he refuses to send a corrigendum or notify the editor.

Comment: Not much you can do, then.

Comment: @OAS For what reason will they not notify the editor? If they're just lazy/busy, there's nothing that says only the corresponding author can contact the editor. Same is true if they have some other reason, though in that case you may need to consider balancing your relationship with them and the importance of correcting the record.